# Android save/rewrite file to sdcard

Tags: java, android

I have implemented method which can save audio resource to sd card, but if i use it 2 times with equal resource i see in Music Player 2 equal files...
How to overwrite file? Or it is problem with player scanning?

```
    public Uri saveToSdCard(String name, int audioResourceId) {

    String path = "/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";
    String resourceEntryName = activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(audioResourceId);
    String filename = resourceEntryName + ".ogg";

    byte[] buffer = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = activity.getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(audioResourceId);
        int size = inputStream.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.oops_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists) {
        new File(path).mkdirs();
    }

    FileOutputStream save;
    try {
        save = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);
        save.write(buffer);
        save.flush();
        save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.ex_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.ex_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    File mediaFile = new File(path, filename);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, resourceEntryName);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, name);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri auri = activity.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
    activity.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, auri));
    return auri;
}
```

Comment: You could check if the file is already existent. If it is, you delete the file and recreate a new one.

Comment: i tried to do         
if (mediaFile.exists()) {
            mediaFile.delete();
} but it didn't help, i still have 2 files

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're sending your broadcast to the media scanner regardless of whether the file already exists or not.

What happens if you put a check for `!exists` around your `sendBroadcast` line as follows?

```
if (!exists) {
    activity.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, auri));
}
```